# Not Throwing Errors in a JavaScript Library

Tags: javascript, error-handling, mootools

On the front page for [MooTools](http://mootools.net/), it says:

> MooTools code respects strict
>   standards and doesn't throw any
>   warnings.

I like MooTools, but having recently read [The art of throwing JavaScript errors](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/03/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors/), I'm a bit confused as to why 'not throwing any warnings' is a feature. If a library doesn't tell you when there's an error (which may be caused because you are using it incorrectly), how are you going to fix the problem?

Why wouldn't you want a library to throw errors?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some javascript frameworks throw warnings due to rules being bent to achieve cross-browser support.  I believe that MooTools' claim is that they don't throw any warnings to the browser in that sense, as opposed to the you doing something wrong with it sense.

e.g. http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/f2926d95fcafb18